# Whats the Regular Expression for validating Decimal Values within range - 0 to 99999.00

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

I am looking for a regex to validate decimal number to be in range of 0 and 99999.00 upto 2 decimal values in AngularJS. I dont want to use max in angularJS, instead I want to use ng-pattern. I tried different expressions but none satisfied all conditions. 
For example -

- 0 - valid
- 0.0 - valid
- 0.00 - valid
- 0.000 - invalid
- 1445.02 - valid
- -34.39 - invalid
- 59999.99 - valid
- 99999 - valid
- 99999.0 - valid
- 99999.00 - valid
- 99999.01 - invalid
- 99999.99 - invalid

Comment: Why not use a numerical comparison? They're numbers after all

Comment: I am doing form validation using AngularJS. So, I want to use ng-pattern.

Comment: You could add your own model validator though. Just because you're using AngularJS, doesn't mean you're limited to `ng-pattern`

Comment: Can you please give example on how I can do it?

Comment: Sure thing ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

Comment: Do you accept leading zeros like `000000000000000000000000099999`?

Comment: If you .split(".") it could be easier to work with.

Comment: Can I just do .09 or must it be 0.09?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
^((?:(?!9{5})\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)|(?:9{5}(?:\.00?)?))$
```

Pretty much, you make sure you don't have 99999 as your number, then match a 5 digit number, optionally with the decimal part. If that doesn't match, then you look for 99999, optionally with .0 or .00.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aW3sV9/1)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @SmitaMore - You're welcome! If my post answered your question, please consider accepting it!